# Der Ursprung des Verbes »heitern«

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Gestern Abend habe ich gut geheitert.

In welchem Teil Deutschlands ist das Verb »heitern«, im Sinne von *schlafen*, entstanden? Sagt man das gängiger im Norden oder im Süden?

Comment: Gibt es das überhaupt? Was soll es heißen? Ich habe es noch nie gehört, und Google findet auch keinen Beleg (nur falsch getrenntes _aufheitern_, _angeheitert_ usw.).

Comment: @chirlu [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH05717#XGH05717) kennt es mit reichlich Beispielen.

Comment: @guidot: Keines davon auch nur aus dem vergangenen Jahrhundert, und keines in einer Bedeutung, die zum gegebenen Beispielsatz paßt.

Comment: Hochdeutsch scheint das nicht zu sein, da nur transitive oder reflexive Formen im Sinn von "heiter machen" aufgelistet sind. Ich würde eine Bedeutung von "meine Gesprächsrunde belustigt" oder "eifrig anheiternden Getränken zugesprochen" vermuten, aber der Kontext gibt das nicht her.

Comment: Na ja, was heißt denn *Nord- und Süddeutschland* des spätestens 16. Jahrhunderts. Mit Schwierigkeiten kann man sich einigen, wo *beliebiges* Wort jetzt benutzt wird. Und was wenn das Wort im Schwerpunkt Deutschlands entsanden ist (Mühlhausen)?

Comment: _Schlafen_, aha. Irgendeinen Beleg für diese Verwendung?

Comment: In Österreich gibt es (nicht Hochsprache) das Wort ['heidln'](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-2587-schlafen-heidln*heidln.htm) (schlafen) bzw. ['Heia'](http://www.ostarrichi.org/word-7402-Bett-Heia.html)(Bett). Vielleicht meinst Du das.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [heitern](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH05717#XGH05717)

Es handelt sich um ein veraltetes Verb, das in der modernen Sprache nur noch selten in Komposita (z.B. *aufheitern, erheitern, (anheitern)*) Verwendung findet.

Usprünglich stammte es vom althochdeutschen **heitaran** ab und hatte zwei Bedeutungen:

- hell machen, aufhellen (auch im übertragenen Sinn)
- ein [schlechtes] Wetter klärt sich

Noch gültige Beispiele für die oben genannten Komposita:

> Nach dem Gewitter heiterte sich der Himmel rasch auf.
> Die drolligen Formulierungen der Kinder erheiterten die Zuschauer.

Comment: Und was würde das dann im Satz "Gestern Abend habe ich gut geheitert" bedeuten? Wurde ich erhellt? Oder habe ich das Wetter verbessert?

Comment: Ich bin auch der Meinung, daß die Antwort voreilig war und vermutlich nicht die eigentlich gemeinte Frage beantworten wird.

Comment: Nun, es wurde weder nach der Bedeutung des Wortes noch nach der Bedeutung des Beipiels gefragt... man will zum Glück nur die Herkunft und Verwendung wissen.

Comment: @emi heitern im Sinne von Schlafen